# How to include _ in a numeric value in properties file?

Tags: java, spring, properties, el, readability

How can I have `_` (underscore) in my numerical property while injecting it with `@Value` annotation in Spring? If I include `_` in my value, Spring throws `TypeMismatchException`.

.properties file:

```
min-score=20_000
```

java class:

```
@Value("${min-score}")
private int minScore;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Spring EL in your `@Value` annotation to replace `_` characters:

```
@Value("#{'${min-score}'.replace('_','')}")
private int minScore;
```